# Last month with company. Company using my profile to bidding a government project

Tags: resignation, contracts, government, thailand

I am new to this topic. Therefore I don't know what are the best tags for my question.
If I ask in the wrong stack exchange site please let me know. I will move it immediately.

**Background:**
I am a senior software engineer. The government project requires the team lead profile with computer science and engineering field as a background and have proven projects. I am the one in the company who can charge in that condition. The rest of them are not.

I am leaving the company within this month. But company claims I have to join the bidding by signing the document. Sign to show my name as a teammate in the project.

It is 50/50 chances to not be investigated since the project is not related to defense technology. It is about inventory managements.

**Questions:**
1. If this situation happen again, should I deny to sign my name in the bidding?
2. Will I damage my name? If government start investigate the team members. Obviously they will not found me in it.
3. Is it common in the west to use short-life member to shore the contract with the government?

Comment: Consult a lawyer, this may have legal implications that we cannot oversee, but I'd strongly suggest not to sign anything of this nature.

Comment: Does your company know you are planning to leave?

Comment: Right now, this minute, you are with the company.  Why wouldn't you sign?  They are not "promising" that you will still be there in a month or a year or a week.

Comment: @KentA. The company knew it not by verbal, but also an email.

Comment: @Fattie Because I am afraid the unknown legal outcome. And no one can confirm that. Do nothing is the safest payoff for me. Consult lawyer is also an option, but since I am leaving. Just keep profile low and stay focus with new future.

Comment: If you don't want to get a lawyer, then at least read whatever they want you to sign very, very carefully. Absolutely don't sign anything that isn't true, and don't sign anything that is misleading.

Comment: @gnasher729 Yeah. You are right. Just now HR told me that company has an unfair contract with me when she checked my contract. Thailand leave period is 30 days. But This company is 60 which is violate the labor law!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the US when bidding on a government contract there are two types of resumes that are included in the proposal: key personnel, and example personnel.

A key person is one that the company is committing to the project. If they win the contract that exact person will occupy that exact position for a specified number of hours for a specified duration of time. In many case they guarantee that exact person full time for the first year.

The example resumes show the types of people they will assign. In some cases they already know who they will be. But in other cases they don't. When they win they ask current employees if they want to switch projects, they may assign others, and in some cases they will hire new employees.  The contract big will typically include one or two example resumes per job description, so on a big project there may be a handful of resumes to cover dozens of employees.

If your resume is being used in the second group, then you have nothing to worry about. If they win the contract after you leave they will find somebody to fill that slot. If they fudge the qualifications of that new person to make them appear more skilled, then that will occur after you leave and doesn't reflect on you.

If your resume is in the first group then there is a bigger issue. You need to make sure that they aren't expecting you to stay. You also don't want them to make it appear that you are staying, because that could hurt the company.

In the US there are ways that the company can replace a key person with somebody else, but it isn't an easy process. I have known of cases where the government accepted the replacement but lowered the rate the company could charge. I have known of other cases where there was no penalty becasue the government delayed the project, and the company could not keep the person on overhead until the government decided to fund the project.